# Is there a better way to pass the variables inside nested for loop from the controller to the view?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a running code below using Laravel 7 (latest version) and PHP 7.4.4 (latest version) but I want to ask if there is a better way to implement.

So basically, the problem lies inside the nested for loop. I want to control the variables *'semesters'* and *'subjects'* in the controller and pass them to the view (index.blade.php). However, *'subjects'* is dependent to the *'semesters'*, thus, I was forcibly written down the logic inside the blade template such as:
`$subjects = $semester->subjects()->where(SOME QUERY HERE)->get()`

See below for the code snippet:

**index.blade.php**

```
@foreach($semesters as $semester)
   @if($subjects = $semester->subjects()->where(SOME QUERY HERE)->get())
      @if($subjects->isNotEmpty())
        //SOME CODE HERE
        @foreach($subjects as $subject)
             //SOME CODE HERE
        @endforeach
      @endif
   @endif
@foreach
```

Is there a best way to implement this one?
Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit**

I am also worried about the query since it is inside the loop. However, I'll just change my design specs to limit the number of *'semesters'* to be shown in the view. This is also to limit the query inside the loop. But, if you have a better implementation, please suggest. Thank you very much.

Comment: "PHP 7.4.4 (latest version)" Latest version of PHP is 7.4.5 at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is eager load some particular **subjects** with their respective **semester**.

```php
$semesters = Semester::with([
    'subjects' => function ($query) {
        $query->where() // SOME QUERY HERE.
    },
])
->get();
```

Now when you call `$semester->subjects` it returns only those filtered subjects.

**Example Code**

```php
@foreach($semesters as $semester)
    @if($semester->subjects->isNotEmpty())
        //SOME CODE HERE
        @foreach($semester->subjects as $subject)
             //SOME CODE HERE
        @endforeach
    @endif
@foreach
```

**Edit**

Now you don't have to worry about querying in a loop. As you see we have already done loading. Which is called **eager loading**

Comment: Thank you so much. I have read about eager loading. didn't know you can actually put some closure function after eager loading. now i learned something.